# Auto Refeshing React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, state

I am trying to implement conditional rendering for our navbar's items depending on what page we're on (i.e. If we are on the chatrooms page, or "/rooms", then we don't want the "Chatrooms" nav item to render in the navbar). What I attempted to do was convert the Navbar into a class component, create a state for the currentPage and set it to window.location.pathname, and then created methods for setting the state and what nav items to render depending on the state, but it always requires me to reload the page when going from one page to another for the conditional logic to fully take effect. Is there a better way of achieving this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `react-router` load content without refreshing the page. It's really simple to learn and use and you could probably get it up and running within an hour. You can Add Route components for the main content of the page.

When you route to a different page you could also call a setState function and change the `currentPage`, which in turn changes the navbar elements.